# My devices cannot see my dlna media center

Tags: macos, network-shares, kodi, media-center

I installed XBMC on my iMac to host as a media center. I enabled UPnP in XBMC. However my BD player cannot see any media center (it can see the Mac as a computer). I know the BD player support dlna. Maybe the XBMC is not broadcasting? Is there another way I can tell if it's working, e.g. from a PC?

Update:
I installed XBMC remote control on my Android phone and it says no host detected, so it's more like my XBMC's problem not the BD player.

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: @jherran Firewall on my Mac? Where is it and what should I check?

Comment: System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Firewall. You have to check is Firewall is on, and if it's blocking your XBMC (this under options).

Comment: @jherran Yes the firewall is ON and it's not blocking XBMC (allowing all traffic).